# How do you abstract out a typescript union to be used in multiple locations

Tags: typescript

So i have a typescript union i want to use in multiple locations and want to maintain it from one spot, how can i abstract it out for larger use?

currently have something like this:

```
function useTemplate(templateName: "default" | "template1" | "template2") {
  var template = templates.find(t => t.name === templateName);

  return { template, columns: template?.grid?.columns }
}

function useTemplateData(templateName: "default" | "template1" | "template2") {
  return [];
}

interface TableProps {
  templateName: "default" | "template1" | "template2"
}
```

I'd hope i could do something like this, but i can't find the syntax for it:

```
type templates = "default" | "template1" | "template2"

interface TableProps {
  templateName: templates
}
```

Comment: `export` the `type` and `import` where you need it?

Comment: `templates` is a type and you are trying to use it as a value ` var template = templates.find`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an array of possible values

`templateValues = ["default", "template1", "template2"] as const`

inside your `type` or `interface` you can use like below

```
inteface TableProps = {
  templateName: typeof templateValues[number]
}
```

Notice

1. `as const` at the end of string array
2. `array[number]`, data type `number` is important here.

Comment: Ahhhh the `as const` Is what got me. Tried something very similar to this earlier but this is what I needed. Thanks

Comment: You can accept the answer if it would've help you :)

Comment: sorry meant to!